# logstash keep matched field in message

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, grok

> 2016-11-30 15:43:09.3060 DEBUG  20
>   Company.Product.LoggerDataFilter
>   [UOW:583ee57782fe0140c6dfbfd8] [DP:0] Creating
>   DeviceDataTransformationRequest for logger
>   [D:4E3239200C5032593D004100].
>
> %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s+ %{INT:threadId}
>   %{DATA:loggerName} %{UOW} %{DATAPACKET} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
>   %{DEVICEID}

The output of that is

```
{
  "timestamp": [
    "2016-11-30 15:43:09.3060"
  ],
  "loglevel": [
    "DEBUG"
  ],
  "threadId": [
    "20"
  ],
  "loggerName": [
    "Tts.IoT.DataLogger.Etl.Core.Filters.LoggerDataFilter"
  ],
  "correlationId": [
    "583ee57782fe0140c6dfbfd8"
  ],
  "datapacket": [
    "0"
  ],
  "message": [
    "Creating DeviceDataTransformationRequest for logger"
  ],
  "deviceId": [
    "4E3239200C5032593D004100"
  ]
}
```

Which is good - EXCEPT - the message is now lacking the DEVICEID property which I extracted. **I want it both - as a separate field and still keep it in the message.**

**Can you do that?**

*(On a side note... how does structured logging like serilog help in this regard?)*

Comment: As of now, `DEVICEID` appears within the `message`?

Comment: Yes, compare the "message" result with the original message ([D:4E32...]) is the DEVICEID (I have a custom Grok pattern for that)

Answer (score 0):

How about try change it

%{GREEDYDATA:message} %{DEVICEID}

to

`%{GREEDYDATA:testmessage} %{DEVICEID}`
then add a field

```
mutate {
  add_field => {
    "message" => "%{testmessage} %{DEVICEID}"
  }
  remove_field => ["testmessage"]
}
```